# JavaScript function not defining properly

Tags: javascript

I've looked every where for a solution to this but found nothing. For some reason when I try to call a function it says that it is undefined.

```
function removeBusiness(num){ 
    companies.splice(num, 1); //Removes a company from the companies array.
    tabCreate(tabsbody[0]); //Reloads the current tab that you are in.
};

var tabsbody = ["tab_name", "element", 0/*is active*/];
var tabs;
function TabCreate(tab){
    switch(tab){
        case "contract":
            if( tabsbody[2] == 1 ){tabsbody[1].remove(); //Removes old tab page and builds the requested one.
                tabs.style.backgroundColor = "#648a64";
            }else{ tabsbody[2] = 1;};
            if( tabsbody != "contract"){
                tabsbody[0] = "contract";
                var submain = document.createElement("div");
                    submain.style.height = "70vh";
                    submain.style.width = "98%";
                    submain.style.margin = "auto";
                    tabsbody[1] = submain;
                    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(submain);
                tabs = document.getElementById("contractlisten");
            };
        break;
    };
};
removeBusiness(0);
```

This is some of my code but I removed a lot of the cases to make it easier to read. I am calling removeBusiness after page has loaded plus 3 seconds. Any help?

Comment: Check the error console, an undefined variable can stop script execution or prevent a thing from being defined.

Comment: You call "tabCreate" from removeBusiness, but you define the function "TabCreate".

Comment: I've tried putting the removeBusiness after the tabCreate function to avoid having undefined variables but still says "Uncaught ReferenceError: tabCreate is not defined". Except that it is already defined

Answer (score 1):

Use a capital "T" when calling the 'TabCreate' function.

**Update**

Javascript is case-sensitive, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Case_sensitivity.

Comment: You are my hero! I've looked at this for a day and a half.

Comment: Why? What makes the difference?

Comment: @electrope Happy to see this issue was resolved for you (and all of the rest of us that hit our heads on this). Please mark this post as the answer so as to expedite resolution for other users in the StackOverflow community.